# MySQL Binary Installation (mysql_install_db)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

While installing from binaries. The below always gives error when we execute from 'scripts' directory

```
[mysql@hostname ~]$ cd /mysql/product/5.6.12/scripts/
[mysql@hostname ~]$ . mysql_install_db --defaults-file=my.cnf
```

**-bash: use: command not found**

But the same works fine when I execute one step back from scripts directory

```
[mysql@hostname ~]$ scripts/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=my.cnf
```

**Question:** Why this happens ?

Comment: I guess it's expecting to be one dir up from scripts, when it's not then something goes wrong & it drops out of the mysql shell, then tries to execute the "use" (intended for the mysql interpreter) in the shell

Comment: Open the mysql_install_db file and go through the script - IIRC it's a text script file.

Comment: It may work if you do ./mysql... ? Specify the path of the my.cnf if it's not in the scripts directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a mistake, you can't execute:

```
[mysql@hostname ~]$ . mysql_install_db --defaults-file=my.cnf
```

Because the correct line is:

```
[mysql@hostname ~]$ ./mysql_install_db --defaults-file=my.cnf
```

You don't have in `PATH` environtment variable the current directory ".".

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you're trying to `source` the installation script by putting `.` (dot space) in front of the script name.  This behaves differently from executing the script.

Prefix the `mysql_install_db` with a `./` instead:

```
./mysql_install_db
```

When you execute it from the level above, you're not including the `.` (dot space), so it executes the script and works as you expect.